# Static Files from Site working, but not from app

Tags: python, django, iis-8.5

Some confusion about static files (Python 3.6 Django 2.. IIS 8.5)
My static files from site are found but the static files from the app are not found.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:81/static/css/pyapp.css 404 (Not Found)

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/pyapp.css' %}">
```

I tried to add

```
STATICFILES_DIRS =[(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'pyapp/static')),]"<
```

to the settings.py but did not help.

Do I have to add a web.config also in the app static like in the site static folder?

```
├───pyapp
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───static
│   │   └───css
|   │   │   └───pyapp.css   <=== this is not found
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───pyapp
|   │   │   └───my.html  <=== this works
│   └───__pycache__
└───pyweb
    ├───static           <=== this works
    │   └───admin
    │   ......
    └───__pycache__
```

For IIS configuration i used this tutorial: http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/running-django-application-on-windows.html

> settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '...'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'pyapp.apps.PyappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pyweb.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pyweb.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-ch'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS =[(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'pyapp/static')),]
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ouh1I.png)

Comment: You haven't really shown enough information here. How have you configured IIS to serve static files? Please show the rest of your static settings, e.g. `STATIC_ROOT`. Did you remember to run `manage.py collectstatic`? You shouldn't need to add `pyapp/static` to `STATICFILES_DIRS` - Django will search your app's static directories by default.

Comment: i added more information

Comment: Your project layout isn't clear to me. Please show where `manage.py` and `settings.py` is. Is there a `static` directory alongside `pyapp` and `pyweb`?

Comment: check the picture link I added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Problem. Thx for help!

I don't understand why IIS is not refreshing the VirtualDirectory. I refreshed x times the website and restarted it.
But the pyapp folder in static was not visible until i set the physical path again.

```
sites
├───pyweb
|    └───pyapp
|    └───pyweb
|    └───static
|    |    └───admin
|    |    └───pyapp   <=== this was not visible in IIS, refreshing not enough!
```

Is this a bug or should I know this?

Answer (score 0):

Always have your directory structure like this.

```
pyweb
|______static
|      |_______pyweb
       |         |______css  
                 |
```

Then run `python manage.py collectstatic`

I found Setting up static files always tricky

Comment: I added one folder more and run collectstatic, but did not help.

Comment: For local environment dont need use collectstatic, this only bring boring problems like run collectstatic everytime you do some chances... i usually only use collect static on external servers

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include your `pyapp/static` directory in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. The `AppDirectoriesFinder` will find it as long as `pyapp` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

You should however include `pyweb/static` (assuming `pyweb` is not in `INSTALLED_APPS`).

```
STATICFILES_DIRS =[(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'pyweb/static')),]
```

You can remove `STATICFILES_FINDERS` to simplify your settings, since you are using the default value.

You then need to run `manage.py collectstatic`, to make sure that `pyapp/static` and `pyweb/static` are collected in your static root.

If your `pyweb/static` directory contains any static files that have been collected there (your question above suggests that perhaps it has the static files from the admin app), then you can remove them. The `pyweb/static` directory should only contain your files that are under version control. Static files from other apps/directories should be collected to the static root instead.

Finally, you need to configure IIS to server your static root folder. I'm not familiar with IIS but it sounds like you are using `web.config` to do this.

If your static files are in `pyapp/static/pyapp` instead of `pyapp/static/`, then you will have to adjust your `static` tag to include the `pyapp` prefix:

```
{% static 'pyapp/css/pyapp.css' %}"
```

Answer (score 0):

No need use STATICFILES_DIRS, because you are using ROOT already, and i do not use STATICFILES_FINDERS  too

Set up like that

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
    )


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**Obs.: You should set up the path like Ojas Kale said**

Restart you server, and you static should be available on localhost:8000/static/pyapp/css/pyapp.css (or any ip or port you setted)

Answer (score 0):

just change `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` in your setting for `STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'` with this django search in each installed apps static directori them in your template use  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/pyapp.css' %}">`

also you can verify with the django command `./manage.py findstatic 'css/pyapp.css'` it returns the path of that file if exist

also you can read about staticfiles [here - django staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I just happened to stumble upon this and step 4 did the trick:

**Configure Handler Mappings for Static Files**
1.) Select the “static” virtual directory
2.) Open “Handler Mappings”
3.) On the right side, select “View Ordered List…”
4.) Move the “StaticFile” handler to the top of the list by selecting it, then on the right under “Actions” click “Move Up” until the handler is above all others. If IIS warns you about diverging from inheriting settings, click OK - this is what we want to do.

Comment: @Welcome to SO! If you answer to old questions (this one is over 2 years old) please check if there's already an accepeted answer (yes) and if your answer provides a significant improvement.